# Change regular TCP/IP communication to SSL

Tags: java, ssl

I have a task to change my existing application from regular TCP/IP (ServerSocket and Socket) to SSL based TCP/IP communication. Currently, Server (`ServerSocket`) is listening on a port and Client (`Socket`) is opening a connection on that port and it is working fine.

So for 10 accounts, we have deployed 10 Server applications (on the same server) which are listening on 10 different ports and respective clients are connecting with respective ports. But now our requirement is to add a secure layer for communication. For that, a certificate will be installed on the server and all 10 accounts' application will be listening on a single port 443.

I have used below code to achieve this but I can not use port 443 and deploy this for all 10 accounts as the port 443 is used by some other application on the same server. Please suggest how to achieve this.

```
SSLServerSocketFactory sslserversocketfactory = (SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
            ssl = (SSLServerSocket) sslserversocketfactory.createServerSocket(serverPort);
```

Comment: I don't think you can achieve that only by this code, you need help on the server side setting. And what *error message* do you get so far?

Comment: Only one process can listen on a port. If you start 10 Server applications, each needs its own port. That was so with HTTP, and is still so with HTTPS. If everything needs to go through port 443 now - for whatever reason - you will need an HTTP(S) proxy listening on that port, which then forwards requests to the specific application port.

Comment: Yuo can't use port 443 in practice except for an HTTPS server, and if you're writing an HTTPS server there is no indication of it here. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Check if you can turn this pure TCP app into something http(s) based

Comment: @Shihe Zhang:  And what error message do you get so far? --> Expected JVM Bind Exception as 443 is used by other application.

Comment: So you need to find out which application using that port. I don't think it's something you can work around with some change in your code. You need the help from the admin of the server. Likely you with end up with using a reverse proxy engine to fix that.

Comment: why not use a tcp proxy/load balancer, like nginx? Such a proxy will take care of SSL termination and proxy the request to the right upstream server without any code change required in your java code.

Comment: You can do TLS exchange over any port, there is no magical specific value. It is just a matter of having the client using the proper default value or using something like `SRV` records in the DNS. Also, even with one IP and port you can have multiple "applications" (like websites) just by having the client use TLS SNI.